# Is server-side Javascript ready for the mainstream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, server-side, derbyjs

I expect within a few years that the server side programming landscape will look very different and Javascript will be extremely popular. That's just my personal opinion.

But what about in the here and now, is Javascript a valid choice of server side language or are the various APIs still too immature? Ie. lacking functionality compared to existing solutions in other languages, and too fast-changing so that they make for an unstable platform? Are the tooling options available up there with tooling options for Java, etc...?

Comment: foursquare uses node.js..

Comment: Isn't it mainstream? so does LinkedIn, Ebay.. and almost everyone when it comes to websockets/sockets

Comment: Javascript has been available at least since 1996 for server side programming as JScript in ASP, and it has looked the same the last decade. It's not because it's immature, lacking in features, or unstable that it hasn't become a dominant platform.

Comment: @Akshat You don't need javascript to handle websockets serverside.

Comment: This site has turned into a joke for closed questions. I search google for a programming related question and end up on SO and at least 75% of the time the question is closed as 'not constructive'. This place is being ruined by over-moderation.

Comment: The question is good but it solicits more discussion on opinions than an actual programming related answer on a programming problem. This question can't really have an answer like everything else here. if you could rephrase it it so it does it could be reopened. You don't **need** Js to handle server side web sockets, but most people will use it via one of the many many modules available such as socket.io, ws...